# execute command from another bot

Tags: discord, bots, nextcord

on my discord bot, i want to create a script that execute **2** commands in a loop, but with different timing. the commands are d! bump (from d-invite) and !d bump. I know this might not respect the discord TOS or might not be possible, but is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I not really understand your issue but hope this can help you. You can try [`on_message`](https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message#nextcord.on_message) in nextcord.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message): #when anyone send a message
    if message.author.id == bot.user.id: #ignore the message sent by bot
        return
    if message.content == 'd! bump': #your first command
        somecode()
    if message.content == '!d bump': #your second command
        somecode_2()
    await bot.process_commands(message) #process the message to application command (do not remove)
```

Comment: this is not what im seraching for. i want to create a function that execute a command from the disboard bot and the d-invite bot.

Answer (score 0):

Those bots probably check if the user who sent the command is a bot, so you likely won't be able to trick it.

The tasks extension in Nextcord is probably what you are looking for though:

https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html

It allows you to execute code in a loop.

```py
from nextcord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(seconds=600)
async def message_loop():
    channel = bot.get_channel(123456789)
    await channel.send("Hello!")

message_loop.start()
```